# Is there a way to extract grouped data directly from room then using it as a key-value pair

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

Say, I have the table below and I want it **grouped into male and female**, I understand I can pass the query directly and get result as ***(List)*** *sorted based on gender*.

However, in my case, I have to group it in code (kotlin) using ***List.groupBy { it.gender }*** which returns a ***Map (key-value pair)*** and its easy for what I am doing that way.

**So is there a way I can directly get a grouped data (from room query) in a key-value pair without having to regroup it again in code?**

Lastly, I will **appreciate any more insights to any answer provided.**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Room 2.4 and higher, you can just use `@MapInfo`.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM person")
@MapInfo(keyColumn = "sex")
suspend fun getAll(): Map<String, List<Person>>
```

Comment: I didn't think about using the sex column directly - thanks for pointing that out (didn't see your response until I finished mine...)

Answer (score 1):

You can [return a Multimap](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/accessing-data#multimap) to do this.

In your DAO:

```kotlin
// Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
@MapInfo(keyColumn = "sex")
@Query("SELECT * FROM Person")
fun getPeopleGroupedBySex(): Map<String, List<Person>>
```

It's intended for relationships between entities, but just groups returned data by the field returned as the specified `keyColumn`.

You need to specify all columns so you can duplicate the `sex` column as the map key. All of the rest of the columns go into the list entities.

Note that you do not need a `GROUP BY` for this to work.

If you only need a list containing values from a single column, you can also specify `valueColumn` in the `@MapInfo` annotation.

Comment: Edited after seeing TheLibrarian's response - didn't need the extra column; can just use `keyColumn = "sex"` directly

Comment: Thank you, both of you for the guidance. It works.